# How to define options for JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object, fetch-api

I have function that requires JS Object as one of the parameter.
And what I wanted to do is define options that can be passed inside that object.
Let me explain what I meant with an example
All of us are familiar with fetch() in js.
In vscode, whenever we tried to pass the object, it auto-completes with options that can be passed
like for code below

```js
fetch(url, {

})
```

when I type say m inside {}, it suggests all available options start with the letter m (method) and when pressed enter we get something like `method: "GET"`

I wanted to achieve a similar feature with my function.

I didn't know what am I suppose to look for to get my solution so I have only done a little research with the closest possible query for me on google but I didn't get any solution for this particular problem.

Just a hint or direction will be fine

Comment: Use destructuring in the function definition.

Comment: You should search for "code completion" or "intellisense" for Microsoft products like VSCode. Generally, Visual Studio will look at the code for the function and figure out the expected properties pretty well, but you can add JSDoc comments to the function to help Intellisense.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "intellisense". "intellisense" is usually a matter of support for the code editor you use. If you're writing Javascript, just look at "JSDoc" and "Type Definition".

Comment: Please have a look at [Tern](https://ternjs.net/), a _code-analysis engine for JavaScript intended to be used with a code editor plugin to enhance the editor's support for intelligent JavaScript editing_. [Read](https://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/tern.html) or [watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wW5VbogkDQ4) about the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is your editor's intellisense hard at work. If you want to achieve the same thing, just immediately destructure the object you're expecting as a parameter.

Try calling this function, giving it an object as an argument and type the letter `n`. Your fancy shmancy editor will suggest `number1` and `number2`

```
const myFunction = ({ number1, number2 }) => {
    return number1 + number2;
};
```

You can also do this without the immediate destructuring by using TypeScript (and ensuring your editor supports TypeScript - if you're using VSCode then it does):

```
interface Options {
    number1: number;
    number2: number;
}

const myFunction = (options: Options) => {
    return options.number1 + options.number2;
};
```